# .gitignore not working the way I expect it to

Tags: git

Thanks for taking your time to read my question.

I am using Linux and am trying to make a repository in my home directory, which excludes everything except for configuration files, that change the display (e.g. themes, KDE configs, etc.)
For some reason, it only works for a few files...

For some reason, it does not include all the things I marked with `!`. For example everything in `~/.config/k*` gets added but the things in `~/.local/share/fonts` is not included... I checked and the directory is not empty but it still does not get saved.

I have no idea, why this is happening. Please help me.

My .gitignore is this:

```
*

!.dotfilesignore # My .gitignore is called .dotfilesignore to not conflict with the global .gitignore. Also changed the git config in the repository to use this file as the excluded file.

!.bashrc
!.zshrc

!**/.icons/*
!**/.fonts/*
!**/.themes/*

!**/.local/share/.icons/*
!**/.local/share/icons/*
!**/.local/share/.themes/*
!**/.local/share/fonts/*

!**/.config/k*
!**/.config/k*/*
!**/.config/KDE/*
!**/.config/plasma*
!**/.config/baloofilerc
!**/.config/PlasmaUserFeedback

!**/.config/Kvantum/*

!**/.config/lattedockrc
!**/.config/latte/*
!**/.local/share/latte-layouts/*

!**/.config/polybar/*

!**/.config/gtk-*/*

!**/.config/nvim/*
**/.config/nvim/plugged/*

!**/.config/neofetch/*

!**/.config/nautilus/*

!**/.config/BraveSoftware/*

!**/.config/i3/*
```

Comment: It could be that these files have already been committed, since `.gitignore` will not exclude already tracked files.

Comment: I don't see the pattern which excludes everything ; does this file also have a line with `*` ? what is your "ignore all by default" pattern ?

Comment: As @LeGEC implies, it doesn't make sense to use `!` do-not-ignore patterns if you don't have a broad ignore patterns, e.g. `*`.

Comment: This is more of a gitdon'tignore file ;)

Comment: You should [read the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)